# Invoking ViewModel related code from Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture

The thing is that sometimes a `Model` should notify a `ViewModel` to show a message box, for example. Sometimes a Model should change the state of a `ViewModel`. What are the proper ways of doing such notifications?

Are there any helpful patterns or something?

Comment: events are clumsy. How about the Observer?

Comment: Don't .Net events already implement that pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single right answer, it is a design decision.

The possible alternatives:

1. Model can expose event members.
2. Model can implement `IObservable<T>` interface or expose the `IObservable<T>` -members. By the way, there is the [Observable.FromEventPattern Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern(v=vs.103).aspx) which allows to convert a .NET event to an observable sequence.
3. Model can use callback interfaces. For example, just to demonstrate the idea:

```cs
interface INumberHandler
{
    void Handle(int number);
}

class NumberViewModel : INumberHandler
{
}

class NumberService
{
    public void Calculate(INumberHandler handler)
    {
        handler.Handle(9);
    }
}
```